# Yii user->isGuest returns false, but shows as guest when printed to screen

Tags: php, yii

I have a really odd problem showing up the beginnings of my authentication for a small Yii app I am building.  I have an "account" table set up in my database that is set up with a different primary key than an AUTO_INCREMENT id.

At this point, I am simply using the tutorial-level UserIdentity file supplied from here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

I'm grabbing the login data from my form using POST and checking it in the controller as necessary.

```
public function actionLogin()
{   
    if( isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) ){
        $identity = new UserIdentity($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);

        if($identity->authenticate()){
            $success = Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
            $this->redirect(array('site/index'));

        } else {
            echo print_r($identity->errorMessage);
        }
    }

    $this->render('login');
}
```

authenticate() returns true when entering proper credentials, and false when I put nonsense in the fields, as it should.  After the authentication, it redirects to the index/home page.

Now, this is the part that doesn't make sense: In the index page, I am checking the state of my user by dumping the getId() method (which I have overridden), as well as checking a state variable I have set.  In addition, when I

```
echo Yii::app()->user->isGuest;
```

to the screen, it returns **false**. Wow, great -- the login should be successful. WRONG.

When I do a dump of the user property of the app,

```
print_r(Yii::app()->user);
```

It shows the CWebUser being empty and as a guest. It's driving me insane.

```
CWebUser Object ( 
[allowAutoLogin] => 1 
[guestName] => Guest 
[loginUrl] => Array ( 
    [0] => /site/login ) 
[identityCookie] => 
[authTimeout] => 
[autoRenewCookie] => 
[autoUpdateFlash] => 1 
[loginRequiredAjaxResponse] => 
[_keyPrefix:CWebUser:private] => ccd216fa11757a8e75e940c97a24ee44                 
[_access:CWebUser:private] => Array ( ) 
    [behaviors] => Array ( ) 
[_initialized:CApplicationComponent:private] => 1 
[_e:CComponent:private] => 
[_m:CComponent:private] => )
```

Any insight? Is there an issue with my configuration or something I may have missed?

EDIT: UserIdentity Class

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
```

{
    private $_id;

```
public function authenticate(){
    $record = Account::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));

    if($record === NULL){
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;

    } else if($record->password !== crypt($this->password, $record->password)){
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;

    } else {
        $this->_id = $record->id;
        $this->setState('username', $this->username);
        $this->setState('friend_code', $record->friend_code);
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    }

    return !$this->errorCode;
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->_id;
}
```

EDIT: I've checked some other things over, and updated my UserIdentity Class.  I can now also get $_id from Yii::app()->user->id OR Yii::app()->getId().

I've found that Yii::app()->user->identityCookie  doesn't exist, and I don't see any cookies other than PHPSESHID in my browser resources.  Is this normal?

EDIT EDIT: So after seeing the first answer, I decided to take a look deeper into the CWebUser class.  It looks like the only piece of the puzzle that may not be working is this line here.

```
$this->changeIdentity($id,$identity->getName(),$states);
// what this method actually looks like:
protected function changeIdentity($id,$name,$states)
{
Yii::app()->getSession()->regenerateID(true);
$this->setId($id);
$this->setName($name);
$this->loadIdentityStates($states);
}
```

Comment: Please add your UserIdentity class codes. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `echo Yii::app()->isGuest` read `echo Yii::app()->user->isGuest`?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- that's what it is in my code -- I just mistyped here. Fixed.

Comment: In order to check authentication (a simple debug), please in your else statement put a return true; and in out of this statement return false;. check if you get true of false

Comment: @AliMasudianPour we don't need to return true or false, because we already know that authenticate() is returning true -- that's already explained in the question.  If it didn't return true, I wouldn't be able to sign in in the first place, and I wouldn't even be asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. Look at the following code from CWebUser:

```php
public function getIsGuest()
{
    return $this->getState('__id')===null;
}
```

It retrieves the `$id`-attribute from your UserIdentity and bypasses the `getId()`-method.

So to fix this, you should either scrap using your `$_friend_code`-attribute and only use `$this->id`, or add the following line in your `authenticate()`-method in the second else-block.

```php
// some code before this
else {
    $this->_friend_code = $record->friend_code;
    $this->id = $record->friend_code;
    $this->setState('username', $this->username);
    $this->setState('test', "test");
    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
}
```

I recommend the first choice, as it tends to be the normal way to do things. But it's up for you to decide.

Hope this helped!

EDIT: another option would be to override the `getIsGuest()`-method in CWebUser of course.

Comment: unfourtunately this doesn't solve the problem.  I've gone back, edited my account table, added ID as an AUTO INCR PKEY, and rebuilt the model class.  Still no change.